# python: how to sort lists with respect to capitalized letters and when first letter, case, and length, their order should remain the same

Tags: python

## input:sort_words ['zero', 'yeLLow', 'Dog', 'Burger', 'x']

**# output: ['Burger', 'Dog', 'yeLLow', 'zero', 'x']**

## input:sort_words ['fish', 'Water', 'Spongebob', 'ball']

**# output: ['Spongebob', 'Water', 'fish', 'ball']**

## input:sort_words ['Pig', 'frog', 'Cat']

**# output: ['Pig', 'Cat', 'frog']**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the builtin `sorted` function, but you need to supply a function to `key` that applies the sort logic you want. Items in your list of strings are equal if the the first letter is of the same case, and the strings are of the same length. Upper case letters are less than lower case letters, and longer words are less than shorter words.

```
def sort_key(string):
    return (string[0].islower(), -len(string))

sorted(['Pig', 'frog', 'Cat'], key=sort_key)
# output: ['Pig', 'Cat', 'frog']
```

Comment: what about the other inputs? input:sort_words ['zero', 'yeLLow', 'Dog', 'Burger', 'x'] and out should be ['Burger', 'Dog', 'yeLLow', 'zero', 'x']

Comment: When comparing two or more strings with the same first letter and case, the longer string has higher priority

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
inputs=['zero', 'yeLLow', 'Dog', 'Burger', 'x']

required_list=[(1 if i[0].isupper() else 0,len(i),i) for i in inputs]

required_list.sort(reverse=True)

print([k for i,j,k in required_list])
```